# Packaging non-SDK app as click?

Tags: application-development, lazarus

I have a program that I created using Free Pascal Lazarus, and I would like to share it in Ubuntu, but how do I pack it with .click?
I have read this
http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/packaging-click-apps/
but my program has nothing to do with Ubuntu SDK, or Qt creator, it is just a Linux program, maybe uses GTK, so how can I pack it with .click?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The `click` packages are designed to be self-contained apps that are currently only supported on the phone/tablet version of Ubuntu. They cannot specify dependencies on other packages (such as free pascal, which is not included in Ubuntu). Once full convergence is ramped up in Ubuntu though, it should be possible to package more apps such as yours, as click packages.

For now, your best option will likely be to create a PPA for your app on Launchpad, and create Debian (`deb`) packages for the dependencies, and the app itself.